# Display JSON response from ajax as HTML or table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

**Code to display json data**

```
$('body').on('click','#check_history',function () {
var settings = {
                    "async": true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": "https://url.com",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache",
                        "postman-token": "bla-bla-bla-bla"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "userid": "this-is-userid",
                        "to": "destination",
                        "count": "5"
                    }
                }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
     //I think I need some code here
    });
});
```

**I get the below JSON response from an AJAX in console**

```
    {
    "status": 0,
    "trxid": "101010101",
    "billpayQueryState": false,
    "billpayState": false,
    "trxList": [{
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:51",
        "transid": 1010101010,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 3500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:25",
        "transid": 2020202020,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 4500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:5",
        "transid": 3030303030,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 4500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 10:55",
        "transid": 4040404040,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 5000,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 10:39",
        "transid": 5050505050,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 5500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }],
    "agentData": {
        "walletType": 0,
        "isWaitingForKyc": false,
        "isAllowToKyc": false,
        "isOutlet": false
    }
}
```

I need to display the JSON data above, to a table or html which easy to read by humans. I've tried in many ways from google & stackoverflow, but has not solved my problem. How can I do it? Please help!

Comment: include what you have tried in OP

Comment: demonstrate any one way from the many ways tried that would be useful to understand what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple map over the response and append the data to the table.

```js
$(function() {
  var response =  {
    "status": 0,
    "trxid": "101010101",
    "billpayQueryState": false,
    "billpayState": false,
    "trxList": [{
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:51",
        "transid": 1010101010,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 3500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:25",
        "transid": 2020202020,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 4500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 11:5",
        "transid": 3030303030,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 4500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 10:55",
        "transid": 4040404040,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 5000,
        "agent": "abc"
    }, {
        "date": "16/1/2017 10:39",
        "transid": 5050505050,
        "type": "merchant_buy",
        "amount": 5500,
        "agent": "abc"
    }],
    "agentData": {
        "walletType": 0,
        "isWaitingForKyc": false,
        "isAllowToKyc": false,
        "isOutlet": false
    }
}
  $.map(response.trxList, function(val, i) {
    var htm = '<tr><td>' + val.date + '</td><td>' + val.transid + '</td><td>' + val.type + '</td><td>' + val.amount + '</td><td>' + val.agent + '</td></tr>';
    $('#table').append(htm);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: that's great code, I just add your code below `console.log(response);` and change the code : `var response = ..... ` become `var response =  JSON.parse(response);`   thanks for saving my time :)

Comment: glad to have helepd